# How to alter a sequence to "NOCACHE" in liquibase?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, liquibase

I have a sequence in my oracle database and the cache size is seted to 20.
I want to alter this attribute to "NOCACHE". But I have to do this through liquibase. How can I do this? I did this chageset:

```
<changeSet author="MY Name" id="2.1">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onFailMessage="The sequence SEQUENCEONE does not exists in the database.">
            <sequenceExists sequenceName="SEQUENCEONE "/>            
        </preConditions>
        <alterSequence                
           NOCACHE
           sequenceName="SEQUENCEONE "
        />            
        <comment>Alter in sequence</comment>        
    </changeSet>
```

I throw me this error:

Attribute name "NOCACHE" associated with an element type "alterSequence" must be followed
 by the ' = ' character. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Not caching a sequence is almost certainly a bad idea.  It implies the sequence is trying to be gapless or act like a timestamp, both of which are impossible.

Comment: We use this id in our screen, and its a requisite that this is always in sequence, but with this cache size, some times the sequence skip some numbers.

Comment: NOCACHE can reduce the gaps but there may still be gaps from rollbacks, exceptions, shutdowns, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquibase doesn't have an attribute to change the caching behavior of sequences. It appears that unless a change is made to Liquibase, you would have to make this change in a custom SQL tag.

Comment: It worked. I did the change inside a <sql></sql> tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

@SteveDonie's answer works well, but alternately you can use modifySql with the createSequence tag to add the NOCACHE to what would be normally be generated.

Comment: done like this
`<modifySql dbms="oracle"><replace replace='CACHE 1' with="nocache" /></modifySql>`